# dynamically create list for hosts in play

Tags: ansible

Assume host-1 has this list:

```yaml
- /tmp/a
- /tmp/b
- /tmp/c
- /tmp/d
- /tmp/e
```

host-2 has this list:

```yaml
- /tmp/b
- /tmp/c
```

host-3 has this list:

```yaml
- /tmp/c
- /tmp/d
```

**Q**: for each host, how can i create a list for matching items across the hosts, and non-matching items.

host-1 his matching list would become:

```yaml
- /tmp/b
- /tmp/c
- /tmp/d
```

the not matching list becomes:

```yaml
- /tmp/a
- /tmp/e
```

and that list is dynamically build for each host.
i must use the magic variable `ansible_play_hosts`, since i want to target current hosts in the play.

i've tried using this code:

```yaml
- name: set fact for shared files
  set_fact:
    shared_files: "{{ hostvars[item].found_items }}"
  loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
  when:
    - hostvars[item.ansible_host].found_items is defined
    - hostvars[item.ansible_host].found_items == found_items
```

the variable `found_items` in this case, contains the list.

Comment: You could have a look into the [`difference` filter – the difference of one list from another](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/difference_filter.html) ...

Comment: Yeah ofc, and i could use intersect and/or union. but my question is more related to, like, how do i implement it... i feel like i should use with_nested, instead of loop as well.

Comment: The not matching list for host-1 would become `a,e`, because `b,c,d` are within the others, right?

Comment: Yes. I’ve edited original post. Only b,c,d. Every list is unique

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with this `inventory.yml`. I integrated your `found_items` there for convenience but that could very well be a register in your playbook/role. See also the below playbook for the `fail` variable to mimic real world scenario and keep only non failed hosts.

```yaml
---
all:
  hosts:
    hosta:
      fail: true
      found_items:
        - /tmp/c
        - /tmp/e
    hostb:
      found_items:
        - /tmp/a
        - /tmp/b
        - /tmp/c
        - /tmp/d
        - /tmp/e
    hostc:
      fail: true
      found_items:
        - /tmp/a
        - /tmp/c
    hostd:
      found_items:
        - /tmp/b
        - /tmp/c
    hoste:
      found_items:
        - /tmp/c
        - /tmp/d
    hostf:
      found_items:
        - /tmp/f
        - /tmp/g
```

Then the following `playbook.yml`

```yaml
---
- name: Calculate matching and non matching items
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    other_hosts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | difference([inventory_hostname]) }}"
    other_found_items: "{{ other_hosts | map('extract', hostvars) 
      | map(attribute='found_items') | flatten | sort | unique }}"
    matching_items: "{{ found_items | intersect(other_found_items) }}"
    non_matching_items: "{{ found_items | difference(other_found_items) }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Artificially fail some hosts to mimic real world
      ansible.builtin.fail:
        msg: this host has been configured to fail
      when: fail | d(false) | bool

    - name: Show the list of other hosts in play
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: other_hosts
        verbosity: 1

    - name: Show the list of other found items
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: other_found_items
        verbosity: 1

    - name: List of matching items
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: matching_items

    - name: List of non matching items
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: non_matching_items
```

gives what you want (or at least as I understood it... run with `-v` to get the intermediate debugging)

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml playbook.yml

PLAY [Calculate matching and non matching items] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Artificially fail some hosts to mimic real world] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [hosta]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "this host has been configured to fail"}
skipping: [hostb]
fatal: [hostc]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "this host has been configured to fail"}
skipping: [hoste]
skipping: [hostd]
skipping: [hostf]

TASK [Show the list of other hosts in play] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [hostb]
skipping: [hostd]
skipping: [hoste]
skipping: [hostf]

TASK [Show the list of other found items] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [hostb]
skipping: [hostd]
skipping: [hoste]
skipping: [hostf]

TASK [List of matching items] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [hostb] => {
    "matching_items": [
        "/tmp/b",
        "/tmp/c",
        "/tmp/d"
    ]
}
ok: [hoste] => {
    "matching_items": [
        "/tmp/c",
        "/tmp/d"
    ]
}
ok: [hostd] => {
    "matching_items": [
        "/tmp/b",
        "/tmp/c"
    ]
}
ok: [hostf] => {
    "matching_items": []
}

TASK [List of non matching items] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [hostb] => {
    "non_matching_items": [
        "/tmp/a",
        "/tmp/e"
    ]
}
ok: [hostd] => {
    "non_matching_items": []
}
ok: [hoste] => {
    "non_matching_items": []
}
ok: [hostf] => {
    "non_matching_items": [
        "/tmp/f",
        "/tmp/g"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
hosta                      : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
hostb                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=3    rescued=0    ignored=0   
hostc                      : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
hostd                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=3    rescued=0    ignored=0   
hoste                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=3    rescued=0    ignored=0   
hostf                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=3    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Exactly the answer I'm looking for. Are there any pointers you can give to make my question more clear. I feel that my explanation is a bit vague.

Comment: Well it looks like I caught it at first glance so I would not be so hard on yourself ;) The thing you can probably enhance (and that probably miss leaded @U880D for his answer) is to make more clear that those lists are host variables (either facts, registers or inventory vars). But then what was expected was pretty clear and there was a code example (even though I don't really know where it was exactly going :D)

Answer (score 2):

Declare the below lists

```yaml
    others: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                difference([inventory_hostname])|
                map('extract', hostvars, 'tmp_dirs')|
                flatten|unique }}"
    match: "{{ tmp_dirs|intersect(others) }}"
    match_not: "{{ tmp_dirs|difference(others) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [host_1] => 
  msg: |-
    tmp_dirs:     ['/tmp/a', '/tmp/b', '/tmp/c', '/tmp/d', '/tmp/e']
    matching:     ['/tmp/b', '/tmp/c', '/tmp/d']
    non_matching: ['/tmp/a', '/tmp/e']
ok: [host_2] => 
  msg: |-
    tmp_dirs:     ['/tmp/b', '/tmp/c']
    matching:     ['/tmp/b', '/tmp/c']
    non_matching: []
ok: [host_3] => 
  msg: |-
    tmp_dirs:     ['/tmp/b', '/tmp/c', '/tmp/d']
    matching:     ['/tmp/b', '/tmp/c', '/tmp/d']
    non_matching: []
```

---

- Example of a complete project for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── host_vars
│   ├── host_1
│   │   └── tmp_dirs.yml
│   ├── host_2
│   │   └── tmp_dirs.yml
│   └── host_3
│       └── tmp_dirs.yml
└── pb.yml
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts
host_1
host_2
host_3
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host_1/tmp_dirs.yml 
tmp_dirs:
  - /tmp/a
  - /tmp/b
  - /tmp/c
  - /tmp/d
  - /tmp/e
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host_2/tmp_dirs.yml 
tmp_dirs:
  - /tmp/b
  - /tmp/c
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host_3/tmp_dirs.yml 
tmp_dirs:
  - /tmp/b
  - /tmp/c
  - /tmp/d
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  vars:

    others: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                difference([inventory_hostname])|
                map('extract', hostvars, 'tmp_dirs')|
                flatten|unique }}"
    match: "{{ tmp_dirs|intersect(others) }}"
    match_not: "{{ tmp_dirs|difference(others) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          tmp_dirs:     {{ tmp_dirs }}
          matching:     {{ match }}
          non_matching: {{ match_not }}
```

---

- Enable the below task before you use the declared lists if you want to allow undefined *tmp_dirs*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        tmp_dirs: "{{ tmp_dirs|d([]) }}"
      when: tmp_dirs_undef_enable|d(false)|bool
```

---

- A larger set

```ini
shell> cat hosts
host_a
host_b
host_c
host_d
host_e
host_f
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/*/tmp_dirs.yml 
tmp_dirs:
  - /tmp/c
  - /tmp/e
tmp_dirs:
  - /tmp/a
  - /tmp/b
  - /tmp/c
  - /tmp/d
  - /tmp/e
tmp_dirs:
  - /tmp/a
  - /tmp/c
tmp_dirs:
  - /tmp/b
  - /tmp/c
tmp_dirs:
  - /tmp/c
  - /tmp/d
tmp_dirs:
  - /tmp/f
  - /tmp/g
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [host_b] => 
  msg: |-
    tmp_dirs:     ['/tmp/a', '/tmp/b', '/tmp/c', '/tmp/d', '/tmp/e']
    matching:     ['/tmp/a', '/tmp/b', '/tmp/c', '/tmp/d', '/tmp/e']
    non_matching: []
ok: [host_a] => 
  msg: |-
    tmp_dirs:     ['/tmp/c', '/tmp/e']
    matching:     ['/tmp/c', '/tmp/e']
    non_matching: []
ok: [host_d] => 
  msg: |-
    tmp_dirs:     ['/tmp/b', '/tmp/c']
    matching:     ['/tmp/b', '/tmp/c']
    non_matching: []
ok: [host_c] => 
  msg: |-
    tmp_dirs:     ['/tmp/a', '/tmp/c']
    matching:     ['/tmp/a', '/tmp/c']
    non_matching: []
ok: [host_e] => 
  msg: |-
    tmp_dirs:     ['/tmp/c', '/tmp/d']
    matching:     ['/tmp/c', '/tmp/d']
    non_matching: []
ok: [host_f] => 
  msg: |-
    tmp_dirs:     ['/tmp/f', '/tmp/g']
    matching:     []
    non_matching: ['/tmp/f', '/tmp/g']
```

---

- To take into account the optional variable *failed* add the below task before you use the declared lists

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        tmp_dirs_failed: "{{ failed|d(false) }}"
```

and declare the variables

```yaml
    failed_dict: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                          zip(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                              map('extract', hostvars, 'tmp_dirs_failed'))) }}"
    tmp_dirs_hosts: "{{ failed_dict|dict2items|
                        rejectattr('value')|
                        map(attribute='key') }}"

    others: "{{ tmp_dirs_hosts|
                difference([inventory_hostname])|
                map('extract', hostvars, 'tmp_dirs')|
                flatten|unique }}"
    match: "{{ tmp_dirs|intersect(others) }}"
    match_not: "{{ tmp_dirs|difference(others) }}"
```

gives (if you set `failed=true` for host_a and host_c)

```yaml
  failed_dict:
    host_a: true
    host_b: false
    host_c: true
    host_d: false
    host_e: false
    host_f: false
```

```yaml
  tmp_dirs_hosts:
  - host_b
  - host_d
  - host_e
  - host_f
```

```yaml
skipping: [host_a]
skipping: [host_c]
ok: [host_b] => 
  msg: |-
    tmp_dirs:     ['/tmp/a', '/tmp/b', '/tmp/c', '/tmp/d', '/tmp/e']
    matching:     ['/tmp/b', '/tmp/c', '/tmp/d']
    non_matching: ['/tmp/a', '/tmp/e']
ok: [host_d] => 
  msg: |-
    tmp_dirs:     ['/tmp/b', '/tmp/c']
    matching:     ['/tmp/b', '/tmp/c']
    non_matching: []
ok: [host_e] => 
  msg: |-
    tmp_dirs:     ['/tmp/c', '/tmp/d']
    matching:     ['/tmp/c', '/tmp/d']
    non_matching: []
ok: [host_f] => 
  msg: |-
    tmp_dirs:     ['/tmp/f', '/tmp/g']
    matching:     []
    non_matching: ['/tmp/f', '/tmp/g']
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    failed_dict: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                          zip(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                              map('extract', hostvars, 'tmp_dirs_failed'))) }}"
    tmp_dirs_hosts: "{{ failed_dict|dict2items|
                        rejectattr('value')|
                        map(attribute='key') }}"

    others: "{{ tmp_dirs_hosts|
                difference([inventory_hostname])|
                map('extract', hostvars, 'tmp_dirs')|
                flatten|unique }}"
    match: "{{ tmp_dirs|intersect(others) }}"
    match_not: "{{ tmp_dirs|difference(others) }}"

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        tmp_dirs_failed: "{{ failed|d(false) }}"

    - set_fact:
        tmp_dirs: "{{ tmp_dirs|d([]) }}"
      when: tmp_dirs_undef_enable|d(false)|bool

    - debug:
        var: failed_dict
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: tmp_dirs_hosts
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: |
          tmp_dirs:     {{ tmp_dirs }}
          matching:     {{ match }}
          non_matching: {{ match_not }}
      when: inventory_hostname in tmp_dirs_hosts
```

Comment: Brilliant as well! I guess you’re just doing for sports :) in essence, you’re saving one variable from the other answer. Still good!

Comment: Believe it or not, at first I wasn't sure what you wanted. I started to read Zeitoutor's solution but I wasn't patient enough. I thought the solution must be shorter. So I started to write my code. Then I realized the point is to remove *inventory_hostname* from the list. I didn't know I reinvented the wheel.